# How to backup azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to backup Azure logic app like Azure app service using azure powershell or from Azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual studio plugin to design Logic apps and commit them from there directly to Azure devops. This way you can build & test locally and deploy once ready with code commit.
Refer following two articles for details
Automate Logic apps deployment using #Azure resource manager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview

& how to design logic apps using visual studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this Logic Apps ARM Template Creator powerShell script for easy repo storage (backup) and deploy from DevOps:

https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator